# Infinite Series of Positive Elements in a $\textrm{C}^*$-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

> Let $A$ be a $\textrm{C}^*$-algebra and let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of elements of $A$. Is it then true that
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^*a_n\ \text{converges} \iff \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_na_n^*\ \text{converges?}$$

I've seen this stated as obvious, albeit in a more general setting in a paper, and I agree that it feels like something that might be true, but I don't seem to be able to get anywhere with it (other than noting its trivial if $A$ is abelian).

My only real attempt went along the lines of if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^*a_n$ converges, then it converges to some positive element $a^*a\in A$, then the obvious guess of what $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_na_n^*$ might converge to is $aa^*$. But then I got no further.

It feels like quite an elementary question, but I'm completely stumped! Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I might have misunderstood but imagine a non commutative $A$ and a sequence $a_n$ such that $\forall n, [a_n,a_n^* ] = \mathbb{1}$ then I doubt this holds. Unless it only happens whenever the sequence diverges...

Comment: @Plussoyeur, Weyl already knew that there is no pair $(T,S)$ of bounded operators such that $[T,S]=1$.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation#The_Weyl_relations

Comment: Thanks @Ruy. Helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the algebra of all bounded operators on $\ell^2$,  consider the operator
$a_n$
defined by
$$
  a_n(\xi ) = \frac 1{\sqrt n}\langle \xi , e_1\rangle e_n, \quad\forall \xi \in  \ell^2,
  $$
where $\{e_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is the canonical basis.  I'll leave it up to you to verify that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_na_n^*$$ converges in norm,  but
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^*a_n$$ doesn't converge, not even weakly!

Comment: Could you elaborate why?

Comment: @Plussoyeur, Have you been able to explicitly compute the partial sums?

Comment: No. How is $a^*$ defined? Is it $\forall \xi \in \mathcal{l}^2, \, a_n^*(\xi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \overline{ \langle \xi,e_1 \rangle} e_n $? And how should I understand $a_n a_n^*$? As $a_n \circ a_n^*$ no?

Comment: No,  the adjoint of an operator $T$ is the unique linear operator $T^*$ such that $\langle T\xi , \eta \rangle =\langle \xi , T^*\eta \rangle $  for all vectors $\xi $ and
$\eta $.  Your proposed $a_n^*$ is not linear:  scalars pull out conjugate.  You are correct in saying that $a_na_n^*$
is the composition of $a_n$ with $a_n^*$.   In fact this is the multiplication operation people always consider for operators.
This is inspired by the fact that the product of two matrices corresponds to the composition of the associated  operators.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Getting there. 
To get the operator, I just need to look its action on the canonical basis $\{ e_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ of $\ell^2$ (so $e_i$ is the zero sequence but with a 1 at the ith entry). Then $\langle a_n(e_i),e_j \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \delta_{i,1} \delta_{j,n}$ so then $a_n^*$ must be defined as $\forall \xi \in \ell^2, \, a_n^*(\xi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \langle \xi,e_n \rangle e_1$.

Comment: And then, each term $a_n a_n^*$ contributes to the nth entry of the sequence, whereas $a_n^* a_n$ always contributes to the 1st entry. While in the 1st case, $\frac{1}{n}$ makes the sequence well-defined, it cannot help the second case as for instance $(\frac{1}{n})_{n \geq 1} \in \ell^2$ would make $\sum a_n^* a_n$ diverge.

Comment: @Plussoyeur, Sounds like you got the idea!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ruy. I had intended to work through it last week, but life got in the way. I get the partial sums of your operators to be $\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}\theta_{e_1,e_1}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n}\theta_{e_n,e_n}$, where I write $\theta{x,y}$ for the rank one operator associated with $x$ and $y$. The first sequence of partial sums doesn't converge pointwise (just putting in $e_1$ is enough right?), so cannot converge in op. norm, but the other series does converge.

Comment: Could you make things simpler and drop the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ part from your examples? Then the first series would be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \theta_{e_1,e_1}$, which still doesn't converge (e.g. put in $e_1$), whereas $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \theta_{e_n,e_n}$ is just the identity. Perhaps I've overlooked something.

Comment: Without the $1/n$, the series $\sum a_na_n^*$ converges strongly, but not in norm.  With it, the convergence in norm is guaranteed.

Comment: Yep, missed that. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ruy , may you explain to me how you found this counterexample? It reminds me of a fourier series in a Hilbert space, but I have no idea how one had to think to construct this counterexample.